# CSS scroll snapping stucks when you try to zoom in

Tags: html, css, multi-touch, scroll-snap-points

[CSS-scroll-snap](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/css-scroll-snap) is working very well. But when you scroll on mobile with one finger, than hold this finger still on the screen and scroll with another finger in the opposite direction (like a zoom ↕), then the scroll-snap will stuck. (regardless on which browser)

It even works on Desktop when you hold Ctrl while scrolling.

I don't know if this is a common issue, but I can't find any fixes or work arounds for this problem.

Any suggestions?

Try it on yourself:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />
            <title></title>
            <style media="screen">
                .container{
                    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
                    height: 50vh;
                    width: 50%;
                    overflow-y: scroll;
                }

                .content {
                    scroll-snap-align: center;
                    height: 50vh;
                    width: 100%;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content" style="background:blue;">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="content" style="background:red;">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="content" style="background:green;">
                    3
                </div>
                <div class="content" style="background:orange;">
                    4
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: don't make it the full width of the screen.

Comment: @kish Wdym? It's not even full width of the screen.

Comment: Could you use javascript for a workaround? Or does it have to be css only?

Comment: @Sirence Only css when possible.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because the two-finger scroll behavior is not yet fully supported by the CSS Scroll Snap feature. One workaround you could try is to disable zoom on mobile devices, by adding the following viewport meta tag to your HTML code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-16">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <style media="screen">
        .container {
            scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
            height: 50vh;
            width: 50%;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        .content {
            scroll-snap-align: bottom;
            height: 50vh;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content" style="background:blue;">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="content" style="background:red;">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="content" style="background:green;">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="content" style="background:orange;">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I hope this solved your problem, otherwise use animation or media querry for better results. Thank You.